# Auto fit column value without increasing row height in LibreOffice

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-calc

I m using **Libre Office Calc** on my **Ubuntu 12.10** desktop and I need a help.

I am writing some data from other resource and save it for each row. I have only 2 columns which values are lengthy and rest 2 columns have only id, but those other column disturb my complete Spreadsheet. Even I tried to set

> Text-Alignment vertical : Top and 
>   checked 'Wrap text Automatically' using **Format Cells** option

I want somehow only few words of those column to be visible so that i can write next row  without scrolling each time, below is the screenshot for better understading, please tell me how to customize this.

[image: Libreoffice Calc issue]

Answer (score 0):

You show the current situation and from what I can read, you would like to keep the row height fixed and only show the first few words of each cell like the example below.

[image]

In the example above, I did NOT set the automatic wrap around (since that causes an automatic adjustment of the row height). In column C, I added a single space, this way the overflow of text from column B is hidden. Cell B1 does show 2 lines because I added text with a line break inside the text. Thus each line only shows the first few words, but once you add a line break (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> WHEN EDITING INSIDE THE CELL, NOT IN THE FORMULA BAR) leads to an extra row being visible. Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: my scenarios is different, there can be white space in column B and i dont want to use any extra column.. as i need to export this

Comment: There is nothing to prevent you from having just a white space in column B. You can remove the [Space]'s from Column C. The text from column B will then overflow over the various columns, right of column B. Is that a problem?